# Doctrine 2. Auto generating proxies

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm

I have a strange problem. I want to turn off the auto generating of my proxies in Doctrine 2. I found this line of code that should do (and does) the trick:

```
$config->setProxyDir(APPPATHSYSTEM."/proxies");
$config->setProxyNamespace('Proxies');

// Auto generate proxies for development
$config->setAutoGenerateProxyClasses(DEVELOPMENT);
```

On my test environment the proxies are located at *application/proxies*. i.e.:

```
application/proxies/BaseUserProxy.php
```

When I'm on the live environment my code suddenly searches for the proxies at *application/proxies/Proxies* which is not the actual location.

I do understand it has something to do with the namespace, but I don't understand why it behaves differently when using the *setAutoGenerateProxy* method.

Any ideas?

**edit**

I did generate the new proxies using the:

```
orm:generate-proxies
```

option.

Which gave me this output:

```
php doctrine.php orm:generate-proxies
Processing entity "Base\Element"
Processing entity "Base\Page"
...
Processing entity "Base\Site"

Proxy classes generated to "/var/www/application/proxies"
```

Looking at the last line, the proxies are generated in /var/www/application/proxies. The directory listing looks like this:

```
BaseElementProxy.php
BasePageProxy.php
...
BaseSiteProxy.php
```

So there is no extra Proxies directory. But when I refresh my webpage it thinks there is, it gives me the following error:

```
Warning: require(/var/www/application//proxies/Proxies/BaseUserProxy.php) 
[function.require]: failed to open stream: 
No such file or directory in /var/www/library/Doctrine/Common/ClassLoader.php on line 148
```

Why is the extra Proxies directory added? If I do generate the proxies on each request it does not look in the extra Proxies directory. Anybody?

**@Bryan M.**: That is not a solution, but a workaround. Besides, it does not work. When generating the proxies they will, if applying your suggestion, be generated in APPPATHSYSTEM and my webapp will try to load them from APPPATHSYSTEM."Proxies". The problem is that the system looks for the proxies on different locations if I use:

```
$config->setAutoGenerateProxyClasses(DEVELOPMENT);
```

If DEVELOPMENT is true, it will look at APPPATHSYSTEM. If DEVELOPMENT set to false, it will look at APPPATHSYSTEM."Proxies". Just switching the DEVELOPMENT constance breaks my application, what theoretically should not be possible.

Comment: Try setting the Proxies directory to just APPPATHSYSTEM. It should pick up the 'Proxies' namespace from there.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think AutoGenerated proxies care.

Instead of pushing autogenerated proxies to production, you should probably `doctrine orm:generate-proxies`, which I suspect will put them in the place your production code is configured to look for them.

Answer (score 4):

Are you developing on OS X and deploying to Linux? OS X's filesystem is case *insensitive*. So I'll often run into a problem where I mistype the case of a class, and it runs and passes just fine in the local environment, but chokes on our server.

So in this case, in OS X, the namespace "Proxies" is able to resolve to "/proxies", but in production, it can't find the class folder, and creates it under "/proxies/Proxies".

Answer (score 3):

If you rename the folder to something called "/temp" you will realize the difference between path and namespace.

The path is the absolute path to the directory the proxies are getting generated into. The namespace is necessary to allow you to configure how an autoloader picks up these entities.

The path in your case has to be something like "proxies/Proxies" and the namespace is then "Proxies". Your autoloader has to be  configured to listen to namespace prefix "Proxies" at directory "proxies/".

This is all mood with Doctrine 2 RC1 though, we found a way to explicitly load a proxy path without help of an autoloader at no additional cost. The Proxy Namespace configuratino is therefore only necessary to make sure no other classes are in the same namespace as the proxies.

Comment: I know the difference between a namespace and a path :). Read my post again for the real problem. Thanks for your reaction though.