# Strange Doctrine EntityNotFoundException

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

I came across a strange behavior with Symfony and Doctrine issue, which actually found out that may be related to [this](http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC-2810) bug.

> request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception
>   Doctrine\ORM\EntityNotFoundException: "Entity was not found." at
>   /dev/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Proxy/ProxyFactory.php line
>   177 {"exception":"[object]
>   (Doctrine\ORM\EntityNotFoundException(code: 0)

To provide some code samples:

```
$nextItems = $this->itemManager->findNextItemByCatId($catId, 2, $allItems);
```

and then I am assigning the two returned results, as follows:

```
$output["next"] = $nextItems[0];
$output["following"] = $nextItems[1];
```

which then are actually returned via an API.

However, when -for testing purposes- I assign random values:

```
$output["next"] = "Test value 1";
$output["following"] = "Test value 2";
```

then no exception and error occurs and the response status is 200, as expected.

Any ideas here?

Comment: First, you use $nextItems like a variable in your first sample, and then like an array in the second. Use it like this : 
    $nextitems[]

Comment: That is because `findNextItemByCatId()' returns an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I struggled with this a few hours then i found two solutions:

1. apply doctrine workaround, at line 758 of BasicEntityPersister

change:

```
    return $entities ? $entities[0] : null;
```

to:

```
    return $entities ? $entities[0] : $entity;
```

2. regenerate symfony bootstrap cache:

   ```
   composer run-script post-update-cmd --no-dev
   ```

   - for 2  i also upgraded mysql to 5.6

Answer (score 2):

Maybe could be obviously, but have you checking if your query return values? About your entity, make shure that is with no error (`doctrine orm:validate-schema`).
And by the way, i've so some problems with proxy directory - normaly on OS X ([Doctrine 2. Auto generating proxies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4096034/doctrine-2-auto-generating-proxies))

Comment: Yes, it does return values, and specifically the expected values.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was focused to much on incorrect annotations (as most responses suggest) and failed to see a simple problem. I had just imported a corrupted database dump.

So if anyone ever has the same problem again:

(1) Use orm:schema-tool:validate to check not only correct annotations, but also if your DB is in sync.

(2) Always check downloaded databases with a checksum!